# If statement giving incorrect results.

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, if-statement

I have this code to add a list to a site (SharePoint). I've added a condition to alert the user if they make a mistake filling out the form. When there's a mistake in the XML I usually use .find("errorstring"). Right now my code keeps giving me the alert that there's an error even though when I look through the XML error string isn't present. Here's the code:

```
function createList(){
  if(!siteUrl){
    alert("You must first select a site");
    return;
  }
  var listName = $('#listName');
  var listDesc = $('#listDesc');
  var listTemp = $('#listTemplate');
  var siteLists = $('#web_siteLists');
  console.log(siteUrl+" - "+listName+" - "+listDesc+" - "+listTemp);
  $().SPServices({
    operation:"AddList",
    webURL: siteUrl,
    listName: listName.val(),
    description: listDesc.val(),
    templateID: listTemp.find(':selected').val(),
    completefunc: function(xData, Status){
      if($(xData.responseXML).find('errorstring')){
        alert('Please fill form correctly');
        return;
      }else{
        alert(listName+" created.");
        siteLists.empty();
        RefreshSiteList(siteUrl);
        listName.val('');
        listDesc.val('');
        listTemp.val('default');        
      }
    }
  });
}
```

XML Response: http://jsfiddle.net/f6tRw/

I figure my if condition is probably not stated properly:

if($(xData.responseXML).find('errorstring')){
        alert('Please fill form correctly');
        return;
      }

Comment: try without the $ ? `if((xData.responseXML).find('errorstring')){...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if($(xData.responseXML).find('errorstring').length > 0){
```

The empty collection returned by `.find()` when there's no match is truthy.

Comment: So if there's a length of 0 does that return as false?

Comment: I've changed the answer to use a comparison, as that makes the intent clearer.